# Solving for variables

Tags: algebra-precalculus

For a recent concert, there were 5650 tickets sold for total sales of \$ 374,666. Price are divided as follows:

1. Premium seats cost \$ 89.
2. Regular seats cost of \$ 65.

How many of each seats were sold?

Solve question fully and show all work.  Please state your variables and solve this question in algebra.

Answer (score 1):

Let $p$ denote the premium seats and $r$ the regular ones.

Then we have

$$89p + 65r = 374666$$

$$p + r = 5650$$

Multiply the second one by $-89$, then add this to the first equation and solve.

Or, solve for $p$ in the second equation and then substitute into the first and solve.